# When I extend an MX class in Flex, how do I reference it in the MXML?

Tags: apache-flex, oop

Meaning, if I have:

```
<mx:Tree>
    <!-- ... -->
</mx:Tree>
```

and I want to change some of the control's behaviour or add functionality, by doing (in AS):

```
class ChristmasTree extends mx.controls.Tree {
    // ...
}
```

how do I change the MXML so that my class is used?

In [the manual it says how to extend components via MXML](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/components_11.html#195546), but how do I do it with AS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, that was lazyweb at its best. Of course it's also in [TFM](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ascomponents_3.html#170709), and actually quite neat. In AS, you do:

```
package myComponents
{
    // as/myComponents/TextAreaFontControl.as    
    import mx.controls.TextArea;

    public class TextAreaFontControl extends TextArea 
    {

        // add / change behaviour, properties etc. ...

    }

}
```

and then in MXML, you do:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
   xmlns:MyComp="myComponents.*">

<!-- ... -->

<MyComp:TextAreaFontControl />
```

Cool.

Answer (score 1):

i think not really the same thing...

your second example u only a import of a custom TextArea component in the main application, that u have already extended in the TextAreaFontControl mxml File. The TextAreaFontControl is a Component, your case something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TextArea xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <!-- her comes the Script block and other suff -->
</mx:TextArea>
```

U extend a Component, by creating a component from an existing Component
What a crap sentance :-P